# Regarding window.onload in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm taking a introduction javascript class and for one of our labs we were instructed to have only **ONE** script tag in the head section but gets delayed by the window.onload event handler.

I got everything to work but my question is why do my imageManipulator() function only work when I do window.onload = function() { imageManipulator() };
and the other 2 works fine without the {}.

Also for my if statement to loop through the hockey teams why won't == 0 work? I thought 0 is true -1 is false so shouldn't it be == 0 and not >= 0?

My code is here:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function christmasDayCalculation()
    {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var christmas = new Date(2016, 11, 25);

        var ms = christmas - currentDate;
        var seconds = ms / 1000;
        var minutes = seconds / 60;
        var hours = minutes / 60;
        var days = hours / 24;

        alert(Math.round(days) + " days until christmas");
    }

    function hockeyTeams()
    {
        var hockeyTeams = ['Anaheim Ducks', 'Arizona Coyotes', 'Calgary Flames', 'Edmonton Oilers', 
                       'Los Angeles Kings', 'San Jose Sharks', 'Vancouver Canucks', 'Colorado Avalanch',
                       'Dallas Stars', 'Minnesota Wild', 'St.Louis Blues', 'Winnipeg Jets', 'Boston Bruins', 
                       'Buffalo Sabres', 'Detroit Redw Wings', 'Florida Panthers', 'Montreal Canadiens', 
                       'Ottowa Senators', 'Tampa Bay Lightning', 'Toronto Maple Leafs', 'Colombus Blue Jackets', 
                       'New Jersey Devils', 'New York Islanders', 'New York Rangers', 'Philadelphia Flyers', 
                       'Pittsburgh Penguins', 'Washington Capitals']

        for(i = 0; i < hockeyTeams.length; i++)
        {
            if(hockeyTeams[i].indexOf("an") >= 0)
            {
                alert(hockeyTeams[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function imageManipulator()
    {
        var numberOfImages = document.images.length;

        for(i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++)
        {
            document.images[i].style.border = "solid red"; // DOM 0 required per lab instructions
            document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].style.width = "100px"; // DOM 1 required per lab instructions
        }
    }

    window.onload = christmasDayCalculation();
    window.onload = hockeyTeams();
    window.onload = function() { imageManipulator() };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="cat.jpg">
    <img src="dog.jpg">
    <img src="bird.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running something in `window.onload` ensure that all the DOM elements will be loaded before the function runs. You need to use this if the function accesses or modifies the DOM.

`christmasDayCalculation()` and `hockeyTeams()` don't access the DOM, so they don't need to be run in `window.onload`. You're not actually running them when the window is loaded, because you didn't put `function()` around them. When you do

```
window.onload = hockeyTeams();
```

it runs the function immediately, and then assigns the value that it returns to `window.onload`.

When you write

```
window.onload = function() { imageManipulator(); };
```

That doesn't run `imageManipulator()` immediately, it creates a function that will call it. You could also write:

```
window.onload = imageManipulator;
```

Notice that there's no `()` after the function name. That sets the variable to a reference to the function, rather than calling the function.

Finally, it makes no sense to assign to `window.onload` multiple times. This is a single property, it can only hold one value. The repeated assignments replace the previous value, and when the document is loaded it will only execute the last one. If you want to do multiple things, you should combine them into a single function:

```
window.onload = function() {
    christmasDayCalculation();
    hockeyTeams();
    imageManipulator();
};
```

---

For your second question, `indexOf()` returns the position of the found element in the array, or `-1` if it's not found. So if you used `== 0`, it would not be true for `New York Islanders`, because `indexOf()` returns `12`, not `0`. `indexOf` doesn't return a true/false value, it returns a position.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification and also the last part makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: This is a single variable -->  This is a single *property*